# how to center a footer div on a webpage

Tags: html, css

I want to center my web page footer and create a reasonable gab between it and the above content. Currently, the footer has a line and paragraph joined to the above content. I can push down the content but the line does not move. I am sure the property I am missing out in my css style sheet. Could someone help?

This is my html mark up:

```
<div id="footer">
   <p>Copyright (c) 2010 mysite.com All rights reserved</p>
</div>
```

Which css property can I use to solve this problem? A sample would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can we see your entire code ? I am sure I can solve your problem in 5 minutes if i can see the code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Center a div horizontally?  Typically done by setting `margin: 0 auto`, or `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto`.

And if you want a gap above it, give it a top margin.

Comment: Block elements take the entire available width, without specifing it you cannot center them but there inline children with text:align:center;

Comment: Hi, could someone please tell me why the footer is working correctly on one page and on another it is appearing mid-way in the web page mixing with  data.

Comment: You might want to create a separate question for that situation, with enough explanations. You should also consider accepting an answer for this question.

Answer (score 35):

```
#footer{
    display: table;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use margin:auto to centre blocks with CSS, and margin-top or padding-top to make a gap above it:

```
#footer {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:2em;
}
```

I've used 2em for the top margin; feel free to change that as you like, even to a fixed pixel size if you prefer. You can also use padding-top as well as or instead of margin-top, depending on exactly what you need to achieve, though the centering can only be done with margin left/right, not padding.

The above code can be condensed using the shorthand margin code, which lets you list them all in the same line of code:

```
#footer {
    margin: 2px auto 0 auto;
}
```

(sequence is top, right, bottom, left)

hope that helps.

Comment: I have not incorporated these new suggestion but based on what I submitted earlier I found at the footer is centered on one page and on the other page that has large table of data, the footer is not at the bottom of the page but rather midway in the data itself. What could be the course?

Comment: He probably wants to center his text, not the div itself.  The div would span the entire width by default anyway, so this only makes sense if you also supply a width.

Comment: I used this: #footer {
 width: 920px;
 height: 100px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 margin-top: 2em;
 padding: 0;
 border-top: 1px solid # and  #footer p {
 margin: 1;
 padding: 30px 0px 0px 0px;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: normal;
 font-size: 12px;
}

Answer (score 3):

I solved it with this:

```
#footer {
width: 100%;
height: 28px;
border-top: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px; 
left: 0px; 
text-align: center; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can center the text with the following CSS

```
#footer {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

If you want more space on top add

```
margin-top: 2em;
```

after the previous margin line. Note that order matters, so if you have `margin-top` first it gets overwritten by `margin` rule.

---

More empty vertical spacing above the footer can also be made using

```
padding-top: 2em;
```

The difference between `margin` and `padding` can be read about [W3C's CSS2 box model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html). The main point is that `margin` makes space above the `div` element's border as `padding` makes space *inside* the `div`. Which property to use depends from other page elements' properties.

Comment: Is margin-top different than padding-top? wouldn't padding-top be more applicable in this case?

Comment: margin is outside the #footer element, padding is inside it.

Answer (score 0):

I used this code for bottom copyright.

```
.footer-copyright {
    padding-top:50px;
    display: table;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    #Panel01 {

    vertical-align:bottom;
    bottom: 0;
     margin-left:auto;
     margin-right:auto;
     width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Notes:

- `#`Panel1 is the id for a DIV and the above code is CSS.
- It is important that the DIV is large enough to contain the items
  within    it.

Answer (score -1):

```
#footer{
text-align:center
}
```

Comment: that would be #footer - the div has an ID of footer, not a class

Comment: all that would do is align the text, not the div itself.

Answer (score -1):

```
.copyright {
    margin: 10px auto 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-style: normal;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ccbd92;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccbd92;
}
```